# Shutdown hangs when samba drive is mounted

Tags: networking, mount, samba, shutdown, fstab

In Ubuntu 16.10, I followed [these instructions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently) to mount a Samba drive. My line in fstab is something like this:

```
//192.168.1.1/hd /media/mp cifs credentials=/home/user/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0
```

When the drive is mounted, Ubuntu hangs if I `poweroff`.

It took me a while to find [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wpasupplicant/+bug/211631) "Network is brought down before network filesystems are unmounted" that seems to be back since 16.04.

I'm posting this question to ask if the old workaround (I'll post it as an answer) is still the best solution for this or the changes in the boot and shutdown sequences have changed this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous workaround for this was to create two softlinks to the script in /etc/init.d/umountnfs.sh. This will unmount the samba drive earlier in the shutdown sequence. I don't know if this could have other undesired consequences.

```
ln -s /etc/init.d/umountnfs.sh /etc/rc0.d/K15umountnfs.sh
ln -s /etc/init.d/umountnfs.sh /etc/rc6.d/K15umountnfs.sh
```

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04 I see `K05umountfs.sh` followed by `K06networking.sh` when running `ls /etc/rc0.d` or `ls /etc/rc6.d`. afaik they are run in alpha order.